# Escape XML CData Tag in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cdata

I am reading an XML using JAXB, but I get null on the value of csNum. CDATA tag has multiple tags in it.
If I remove the CDATA tag from the XML file, I will get csNum.   How do I ignore the CDATA tag when I convert xml to java class?

this is the xml file I post on postman:

```
enter code here` <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:icon="Test.Source.Main.ws.provider:Reporting">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <icon:getLocations>
             <XMLString>
    <![CDATA[
            <Locations>
                <csNum>05914460</csNum>
            </Locations>
    ]]>
             </XMLString>
             <UserTokenString>?</UserTokenString>
          </icon:getLocations>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

```
class GetLocations and LocationsOuter are auto-generated by Jax-B. if there is no CDATA tag, I will get the csNum correctly; is there a way to add an annotation in here to ignore the CDATA tag? :
```

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "getLocations")
    public class GetLocations
        implements Serializable
    {
    
        private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @XmlElement(name = "XMLString", required = true, nillable = true)
        protected LocationsOuter xmlString;
        
        public LocationsOuter getXMLString() {
            return xmlString;
        }     

  ...
    }
```

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class LocationsOuter
        implements Serializable
    {
    
        @XmlElement(name = "Locations", required = true, nillable = true)
        protected Locations locations;
    

        public Locations getLocations() {
            return locations;
        }
    
    }
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Locations
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String csNum;
    @XmlElement(name = "Location", nillable = true)
    protected List<Location> location;

...

}
```

Comment: For an XML parser the content inside CDATA is plain text. The only way is to extract this text and parse it separately with an XML parser.

Comment: Vanje, you are right. I have to parse XML again.